# Derivative of trace of matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I'm new to matrix calculus and I have a problem with my assignment. Following is a function of trace of matrices:
$$
 f =
 \mathrm{tr}[\mathbf{X} \mathbf{X^T}]
 - \mathrm{tr}[\mathbf{X} \mathbf{H^T} \mathbf{W}^T]
 - \mathrm{tr}[\mathbf{W} \mathbf{H} \mathbf{X}^T]
 + \mathrm{tr}[\mathbf{W} \mathbf{H} \mathbf{H}^T \mathbf{W}^T].
$$

And I have to prove that:
$$
 \frac
 {\partial \mathrm{tr}[
  (\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{W}\mathbf{H})
  (\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{W}\mathbf{H})^T
  ]
 }
 {\partial W}
 = -2 \mathbf{X} \mathbf{H}^T
   + 2 \mathbf{W} \mathbf{H} \mathbf{H}^T.
$$

In the second equation, the numerator is f in the fist equation. Can you help me solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(W)=\mathrm{Constant}-2\mathrm{tr}(XH^TW^T)+\mathrm{tr}(WHH^TW^T)$.

The derivative is $$
\begin{align*}
Df_W:Z\rightarrow &-2\mathrm{tr}(XH^TZ^T)+\mathrm{tr}(ZHH^TW^T)+\mathrm{tr}(WHH^TZ^T)\\
&=-2\mathrm{tr}(XH^TZ^T)+2\mathrm{tr}(ZHH^TW^T)\\
&=-2\langle XH^T,Z\rangle+2\langle WHH^T,Z\rangle.
\end{align*}$$

Thus the gradient is $\nabla(f)(W)=-2XH^T+2WHH^T$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's correct, but I think it should be Dfw instead of Dfx, no?

Comment: You are right. Edited.

Comment: @loupblanc, you seem to have a good understanding of matrix calculus, can you recommend learning resources you have found helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Sorry for posting the image but I don't know how to type formulas on this text box. My solution uses denominator notation as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Denominator-layout_notation)

Most of formulas mentioned in the solution also from Wiki, please have a look if you are confused.[image]

Comment: You use formulas without understanding them. I think this is not a good idea. Learn to calculate derivatives and deducing gradients.